# sqlalchemy change queried object after filters have been applied?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Say I have a query object

```
query = session.query(SomeModel) \
    .filter(SomeModel.foo == 'bar') \
    .filter(SomeModel.active == True)
```

Can you modify the object list prior to executing the query, maintaining all the same filters

i.e.

```
.change_query(SomeModel.id, SomeModel.name)
```

so that the resulting query object is:

```
session.query(SomeModel.id, SomeModel.name) \
    .filter(SomeModel.foo == 'bar') \
    .filter(SomeModel.active == True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow already found the answer. Will leave this open in case people are searching for this:

```
query = query.with_entities(SomeModel.id, SomeModel.name)
```